# Session::flush is not working at first try in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-8

I have this straightforward code that directly logouts the user but sometimes it doesnt clear the session.
Note that this is on the service layer

```
public function logoutUser(): array
{
    Session::flush();
    Session::save();
    return [
        LoginConstants::BOOLEAN_RESULT => true,
        LoginConstants::APP_ID         => $this->oUtility->getAppId()
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Laravel own documentation suggest to do that:

```
/**
 * Log the user out of the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    Auth::logout();
 
    $request->session()->invalidate();
 
    $request->session()->regenerateToken();
 
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to logout then use ,

> Auth::Logout();

[Docs..](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication#logging-out)

If You Want to Flush Session You can try ,

> $request->session()->flush();
> $request->session()->invalidate();

Read Documentation [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/session#deleting-data)

Answer (score -1):

If you would like to remove all data from the session, you may use the flush method:

```
/**
 * Log the user out of the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */

public function logout(Request $request)
{
    Auth::logout();
 
   $request->session()->flush();
}
```